# Unable to refresh database and its table schema in DataGrip

Tags: database, schema, datagrip

Whenever I refresh my database in IDE (Datagrip, Goland), I get an error saying 'org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: user MY_USER does not have SELECT privilege on relation Inventory.' Not sure why, but I am able to run SELECT queries in the same IDE console on the table Inventory. I can even log into my db cli and run queries without any issues. Can someone help?